# Solution-wide #define

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to globally declare a #define?

Like I want to have a file that has for instance,

```
#define MONO
```

and I want all source-code files to know that this pre-processor directive is defined. How would I achieve that?

Comment: Here there is answer that meets the requirement: "#define Constant on a Solution Basis" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268177/is-there-anyway-to-define-constant-on-a-solution-basis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is There anyway to #define Constant on a Solution Basis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268177/is-there-anyway-to-define-constant-on-a-solution-basis)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Update: You cannot do a "solution-wide" define afaik, however the answer below is workable on a per-project basis.

You set them in your Compilation Properties or Build options:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/76zdzba1(v=VS.80).aspx (VS2008)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/76zdzba1(v=VS.100).aspx (VS2010)

see the "To set a custom constant" heading.

**Update**

[Microsoft Documentation on Build Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CS.PROJECTPROPERTIESBUILD%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)

You get to the build options by right-clicking the project and selecting properties from the menu.

[image: Project Build Options]

Comment: I don't have a compile tab either. VS2010

Comment: I don't think this answers the question regarding a _solution_ wide `#define`?

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and is misleading wasting peoples time.

Comment: Does not address the question that we came here to learn about.

Answer (score 24):

I know solution for C# projects (I don't tested it for any other projects)

For example you have:

```
Project1\
Project2\
Solution1\Solution1.sln
Solution2\Solution2.sln
```

Create `SolutionDefines.targets` file in solution directory

```
Project1\
Project2\
Solution1\Solution1.sln
Solution1\SolutionDefines.targets
Solution2\Solution2.sln
Solution2\SolutionDefines.targets
Solution3\Solution2.sln
Solution3\|no target file|
```

in each project file add:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)SolutionDefines.targets" Condition="exists('$(SolutionDir)SolutionDefines.targets')" />
```

In `Solution1\SolutionDefines.targets` add:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);TRACING_BUILD</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

In `Solution2\SolutionDefines.targets` add:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);ANOTHER_DEFINE</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

In this case you have:

For Solution1 - all projects have `TRACING_BUILD` define added

For Solution2 - all projects have `ANOTHER_DEFINE` define added

For Solution3 - all projects - no defines added

In this approach you must store all solutions with solution wide defines in separate directories

Comment: Got it to work with two more infos, thanks a lot! 1) In the `SolutionDefines.targets` file I had to declare `<Project>` without any attributes, so it worked also with new "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" projects. 2) The include must be placed _after_ all other `<DefineConstants>` of the project.

Comment: The best (and the only, i guess) way to keep the things DRY

Comment: For some reason I need to rebuild the project/solution twice in order for changes in `SolutionDefines.targets` to have effect and VS intellisense does not always detect changes even after reloading the solution.

Answer (score 24):

Years later, and similar to Alexei's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51668898/3195477) but supported innately.

One can make a `Directory.Build.props` similar to a `NuGet.Config` file as per

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019

Ours looks like:

```xml
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DefineConstants>RC_427</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And it effectively includes this into all CSPROJ files in your SLN.  For some reason that particular solution is insanely hard to find via google.  Been around since MSBuild 15

Comment: Also note it seems if you change the constants in this new global solution file, you'll have to unload and re-load each vs project in order for VS intellisense to pick up the change (the ms build will pick up the change fine however).

Comment: This solution is great for projects using the new SDK-style project format but projects using the old non-SDK-style project format have issues using `Directory.Build.props`. See [.props File Properties Not Reloaded When Changed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/187797/props-file-properties-not-reloaded-when-changed.html)

Comment: Does not work for me with Azure SF project in C#. Unload/Reload/Rebuild the project does not help.

Comment: MSBuild can correctly support this feature, but even VS 2022 need be restarted after editing Directory.Build.props file. 2 years passed and this bug is not fixed :-(

Comment: Can someone explain exactly how to do this. The MSDN article suggests dropping the file "in the root where all your source lies". I've done exactly that with the example in the answer, restarted VS 2019...and the symbol is not detected in code. Is there something more than just dropping a file in a folder somewhere, like a project or solution setting that needs to change?

Comment: Updates to solution based `Directory.Build.props` seems to propagate on the fly to sub-project settings if this file is added to the Solution Items (via Solution->Add->Existing Item)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a way to create a *solution-wide* #define. You can create one for each project/assembly, as the other answers have described, but you'll need to do this for each and every project in the solution if you need *all* source code files to know of that #define.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the answers @Murtago and @Mark Cidade to make it solution wide:

Open the configuration manager for the solution and create a new configuration (copied from the closest match) then change conditional symbols for the projects that need different ones.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In case you have both C# and C++ projects in the solution and need to share preprocessor definitions among them.
Create some `SolutionDefines.targets` file near your `*.sln` as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MY_DEFINITION</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>MY_DEFINITION;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Then add to C/C++/C# `*.vcproj`/`*.vcxproj`/`*.csproj` project files this line somewhere in the end

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)SolutionDefines.targets" Condition="exists('$(SolutionDir)SolutionDefines.targets')" />
```

Ok, now you can enjoy `#if MY_DEFINITION` in C# and `#ifdef MY_DEFINITION` in C/C++. Visual Studio C# editor doesn't like this way and tells there is no `MY_DEFINITION` defined. But, C# compiler csc.exe gets the symbol properly.

Answer (score 3):

There is one more workaround, correct me if i'm wrong:

For example, `ProjectA` references `ProjectB`, and `ProjectsCommon` contains base static variable. Both projects refernece `ProjectsCommon`.

Code in `ProjectsCommon`:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ProjectA")]

------------------------------------------

public class ConditionVariables
{
    public static bool IsABC { get; internal set; } = false;
}
```

Code in `ProjectA`:

```
#if ABC
    ProjectsCommon.ConditionVariables.IsABC = true;
#endif
```

Code in `ProjectB`:

```
if (ProjectsCommon.ConditionVariables.IsABC )
{
    // first scenario
}
else
{
    // second one
}
```

However, code in `ProjectA` should run first. This is probably good when `ProjectA` is a bootstarapper project.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new solution configuration in Configuration Manager and make sure that the box is checked to create new project configurations as well. And then in the *Build* properties of each project enter `MONO` into the *Conditional compilation symbols* box.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of being solution-wide?

Answer (score 2):

in vs 2013 you can use /define:x or /d:x http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx

Comment: this option has been there forever, not only VS2013, but it sets options for a single compilation, not defining a macro for the whole solution

Answer (score 1):

The proper place for a pre-processor directive is the VS build configuration. If you are using a command line to build your solution you can also pass it using /define option.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of being solution-wide?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a solution wide definition, but I was able to quickly add a preprocessor definition to all projects by doing the following:

1. hold ctrl and select each project
2. right click on any selected project and choose `Properties`
3. go to `C/C++` --> `Preprocessor`
4. click the little down arrow beside `Preprocessor Definitions`
5. choose `<Edit...>`
6. add my definition after `<different options>`
7. `OK` out of the menus

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 with a C code base.

Comment: Can a function-like macro be added? Something like `#define IS_DOUBLE(X, Y) ((Y * 2 == X) ? 1 : 0)`. How can something like this be added globally?