# Conditional Compilation Symbols

Tags: c#, .net

i have 2 projects on my solution (in this case, both C# - could be VB/C#) and in one of these projects i have compilation symbols defined on the Properties > Build > Conditional Compilation Symbols tab.

Let's say i defined: BUILDLIBABC.

What i want is to be able to define this compilation symbol on 1 project and use it on all projects on my solution. The symbol is defined on "mylib1" (a DLL project) and i want to use that on my EXE project "myexe1" (an Windows Forms project) so, when i set this symbol on/off, the code on the EXE project is set as well.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Another possible workaround:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268177/is-there-anyway-to-define-constant-on-a-solution-basis

Comment: Should be the dupe target IMHO (the current one says this is not possible). I'll fix that if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check the references.