# Preprocessor directives across different projects

Tags: c#

Now before this is marked as duplicate I saw [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836501/preprocessor-directives-across-different-files-in-c-sharp), [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771195/is-it-possible-to-keep-precompiled-symbols-in-c-sharp-assemblies-for-use-in-a-re?noredirect=1&lq=1), [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149351/solution-wide-define) questions, but I don't really think they are a good fit to my scenario.

I'm dealing with **badly written**, **evil** code that I have no choice but to use in unit tests. It is essentially a library to read and merge some special formatted config files. Now in the code assumption is made that it will be used from executable applications, so it tries to load `.exe` config files. Obviously this is not the case if used from unit tests, so it fails by throwing an exception.

To somehow overcome this limitation, I want to use preprcessor directives to change some parts of the code when used from unit test project.

Let's say I have 3 projects.

1. Class library project -> **Evil**
2. Console application project -> **Proj1** (references **Evil**)
3. Unit test project     -> **Test1** (references **Proj1** and **Evil**)

**Test1** & **Evil** have additional `UNITTEST` symbol defined (Build tab -> Conditional compilation symbols), and **Evil** has some code like this

```
#if !UNITTEST
// do evil stuff
#else
// do stuff for unit test
#endif
```

Now what I want is to define `#UNITTEST` in **Test1** project's test class and have it reflected in **Evil** project.

From what I've seen in other answers - the only suggested way is to build with proper symbols for each case (when running unit tests, when debugging locally, when preparing a package for release), which looks cumbersome to me.

What I'm looking for is a way to do less manual intervention and be able to easily have the version I need. As an example, when I build and **Test1** has `UNITTEST` symbol defined then **Evil** is built with `UNITTEST` symbol as well (and copied to **Test1's** output) and the **Proj1** will always reference version of **Evil** built with `DEBUG` or `RELEASE` based on **Proj1's** setup.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

I'm open to other suggestions to solve the problem. 
Unfortunately refactoring/replacing **Evil** with something else is not an option (too much effort which can't be done now).

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to cascade precompiler directives ?

Comment: I guess this post has 2 questions - is it possible to cascade precompiler directive & if so how ?

Comment: Then the answer is "no". C# does not support #include so a directive to the compiler cannot be applied to multiple projects in a VS.net solution.

Comment: If the only issue you are trying to solve is to open config from 'exe' file - then why not just create a copy of .config.dll -> .config.exe during tests build?

Comment: @Lanorkin thanks or the input - that's not the only issue unfortunately (otherwise that small piece could have been refactored). There are many other similar assumptions. I brought `.exe` config example only for the sake of clarity.