# how to declare common #define for several projects under the same solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros, versioning, definition

I have several projects under the same solution .
I want to add this to all my .rc  files:

```
#define STR(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STR(x)
#define TESTER STRING(MACRO1.MACRO2)

MACRO1 = 9
MACRO2 = 10
these are two macros that I added at the property pages using : "User Macros"
```

I thought using the same "User macros" but how can I declare macro with a parameter input there?
I also thought using header files but still it's duplication..

Is there a way to define these STR and STRING in common properties? or somehow just for my projects to read them ? Instead of adding the same code to all my sources?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149351/c-solution-wide-define

Comment: I see that I can define a constant, but here I have STR(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a header file containing all the global data and put it in solution directory. Then add this file to your solution as an existing item. For example `defines.h` :

```
#pragma once
#define STR(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STR(x)
#define TESTER STRING(MACRO1.MACRO2)

MACRO1 = 9
MACRO2 = 10
```

You can address this header with a relative address anywhere needed like this (assuming you have a folder for each project):

```
#include "../defines.h"
```

Or you could just add the address to your Additional Include Files in project.